# Find a two digit number with recursion

Tags: c, recursion, numbers

I'm trying to code something in C by using recursion.

The user writes **two positive numbers of same length** and the program gives him a new number, which is composed like this :

new number unity digit = the smallest digit in the second positive number that the user wrote.

new number ten digit = the biggest digit in the first positive number that the user wrote.

Very simple in fact, here is an example :

`5642` and `2371`

will give us : `61`.

---

I tried something like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calcPair(int a, int b){

    int number = calcPair(a/10, b/10);
    int digit1 = (number/10);
    int digit2 = number%10;

    if(digit1 < a%10){
        digit1 = a%10;
    }
    if(digit2 > b%10){
        digit2 = b%10;
    }

    return(number);
}

int main()
{
    int a, b, number=0;
    printf("Please enter two positive number of same length:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);

    calcPair(a, b);
    printf("The two-digit number composed from %d, %d is: %d", a, b, number);
    return 0;
}
```

BUT the program doesn't run at all.. and closes.

**Maybe someone can correct me ? Or helping me finding the mistake**.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Idea: Since its "user writes two positive numbers", use `unsigned` rather than `int`.  Likely will not affect your present problem though.

Comment: just looking at your code, it just keeps calling itself with its inputs divided by 10.  You have infinite recursion.  You need to have a path where it just returns an answer and not a call to itself.

Comment: @Jim : something like : if digit 2 == .. && digit 1 == .. so return(number) ? Thanks.

Comment: I see now that it's an infinite recursion but I'm not sure to know how to correct this..

Comment: Use each recursive step to store a set of digits, and then compare with the return, and return the amended result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
int calcPair(int a, int b){
    int number;
    if (a < 10 && b < 10) {
        number = a*10 + b;
    } else {
        int digita = a%10;
        int digitb = b%10;
        number = calcPair(a/10, b/10);     

        if(digita > number/10){
            number = digita*10 + number%10;
        }

        if(digitb < number%10){
            number = (number/10)*10 + digitb;
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

Also, a small fix to the main:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, number=0;
    printf("Please enter two positive number of same length:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);

    number = calcPair(a, b);
    printf("The two-digit number composed from %d, %d is: %d", a, b, number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the explanation, but when I tested your code, I always got 0 as a result.. @Jim

Comment: It was a framework; I'm not sure I got the particulars correct.

Comment: You have to return calcPair() into number in your main; see above.

Comment: :) I was working on my main too ! Because yes, I paid attention there is a problem there too..

Comment: I thought it will work like this but I get some compilation errors like : `|25|error: implicit declaration of function 'printf' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]` and `|26|error: implicit declaration of function 'scanf' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]`

Comment: @Jim - I believe you are missing two `}`.  (after ...if(digita..., ...if(digitb... in else block.  (reason for OP compiler errors.)  After fixing those, your code builds OK.

Comment: No No ! It's ok I added them :) And I didn't say nothing ! It was my fault, his code works. (Don't paid attention to these errors).

Answer (score 3):

Your recursion can never end.  Consider the following line in `calcPair`:

```
int number = calcPair(a/10, b/10);
```

This statement will always be executed unless you make it conditional, such as:

```
int number;
if((a != 0) || (b != 0))
    number = calcPair(a/10, b/10);
```

Eventually, because you're dividing both numbers by 10, this condition will prove `FALSE`.

Comment: Hi @Fidding Bits, like for the second answer, when I tested your code, I always get 0 as a result.

Comment: I understand that I have to put a condition to stop the recursion and avoid a mistake, but the condition you wrote doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user3605367 The recursion will end, with the fix that I suggested, however, your logic in `calcPair` is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

***Whether or not you are allowed to*** (you did not specify in OP),
here is a *recursive search method* using ***strings*** :

***Strings*** are just an array of `char`.  because you are interested in distinguishing the individual digits within a larger integer, the `char` data type will be a sufficient size container to facilitate the comparison.
Using arrays of `char` (strings) within a recursive function with exit criteria of `strlen()` > 0 will allow you to walk through each *integer*, and select the appropriate value (min or max).
***This approach uses two recursive functions***:  `getMinDigit()` and `getMaxDigit()`, both returning a char representing the maximum value digit, or minimum value digit of their respective original multi-digit integer.  These results are then concatenated, and converted back into a two digit integer.

***Here is the example code*** that given:

5642 and 2371

will give us : 61.

```
char getMinDigit(char *digit)
{
    static char val='9';//largest single digit base 10
    int len=0;
    if(strlen(digit) > 0)
    {
        len = strlen(digit);
        if(digit[len-1] < val) //test for smallest char in string
        {
            val = digit[len-1]; 
            digit[len-1] = 0;
            getMinDigit(digit);
        }
        else 
        {
            digit[len-1] = 0;
            getMinDigit(digit);
        }

    }
    return val; 
}

char getMaxDigit(char *digit)
{
    static char val='0'; //smallest single digit base 10
    int len=0;

    if(strlen(digit) > 0)
    {
        len = strlen(digit);
        if(digit[len-1] > val) //search for largest char in string
        {
            val = digit[len-1];
            digit[len-1] = 0;
            getMaxDigit(digit);

        }
        else 
        {
            digit[len-1] = 0;
            getMaxDigit(digit);
        }
    }
    return val; 

}

int calcPair(int a, int b)
{
    char big[10]={""}, small[10]={""};
    char Big, Small;
    char result[3]={""};
    sprintf(big, "%d", a);
    sprintf(small, "%d", b);
    Big = getMaxDigit(big);  //recursive function
    Small = getMinDigit(small); //recursive function
    sprintf(result, "%c%c", Big, Small);
    return atoi(result);

}



int main(void)
{
    int result = calcPair(5642, 2371);
    printf("%d", result);
    return 0;
//for illustration, hard coded to OP values
        //int a, b, number=0;
        //printf("Please enter two positive number of same length:\n");
        //scanf("%d", &a);
        //scanf("%d", &b);

        //calcPair(a, b);
        //printf("The two-digit number composed from %d, %d is: %d", a, b, number);
        //return 0;



}
```

Comment: Nope I can't use strings here :) BUT thanks for the method, very interesting in fact. @ryyker.

Comment: Too bad :) strings, in this problem are easy to manipulate and read.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refactor your code to be more expressive of your requirement, with a few helper functions.

```
int greater(int a, int b)
{
   return (a>b);
}

int less(int a, int b)
{
   return (a<b);
}

int pickDigit(int n, int (*func)(int, int))
{
   int ret = n%10;
   n /= 10;
   while ( n > 0 )
   {
      if ( fun(n%10, ret) )
      {
         ret = n%10;
      }
      n /= 10;
   }
   return ret;
}

int getBiggestDigit(int n)
{
   return pickDigit(n, greater);
}

int gteSmallestDigit(int n)
{
   return pickDigit(n, less);
}

int numDigits(int n)
{
    int ret = 0;
    while (n > 0 )
    {
       ++ret;
       n /= 10;
    }
    return ret;
}

int calcPair(int a, int b)
{

    if ( numDigits(a) != numDigits(b) )
    {
        // Deal with error.
    }

    return betBiggestDigit(a)*10+getSmallestDigit(b);
}
```